# React Native gradle executionHistory.bin too big

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I've recently upgraded my react-native app to version 0.60.5, as to fulfil App Store requirement of 64-bit app, but I've noticed that the executionHistory.bin file inside `android/.gradle/x.x.x/executionHistory` got really big, going from ~6Mb, to ~100Mb, which is a real pain as GitHub won't allow files larger than 100Mb to be uploaded. I searched a way to clean the file, delete it and recreate it but really haven't found much. I want to know how to solve this issue, if I screw up upgrading my rn version or something.

Specs:

OS: 
macOS Catalina 
version: 10.15.1

React-Native: 0.60.5

Comment: Why is it under source control in the first place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.gradle` directory should be added to the `.gitignore`. There is no need to have this in version control as it is just used to store some build cache and various things that get re-generated when gradle builds.

My suggestion... Delete the `.gradle` directory locally and from your git repo (it will regenerate next time you build android). Then add it to your `.gitignore`.

See here for the recommended ignore file for react-native (created by react-native):
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/template/_gitignore

Comment: What about the app-debug.apk can I also add it to the .gitignore? I'm facing in these executionHistory and app-debig.apk files.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are having this issue **AFTER committing and pushing**...

I just realized I had this issue when cloning a large repo (~470MB).

I used https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo to inspect large objects that were bloating the git history, and found `executionHistory.bin`, `node_modules` and all kinds of other shit that should never have been checked in the first place.

I made a list of files a directories to delete from history and added them in a file `to_delete.txt`, in the directory one level above my repo:

```
# Files and directories to delete

android/.gradle
node_modules
...
```

And then:

```
git filter-repo --invert-paths --paths-from-file ../to_delete.txt --force
```

Note the `--force` option, because I was getting wrong warnings about my repo not being a fresh clone.

After this, my repo size is just above 6MB, which makes much more sense for the small-ish project that it is

Hope this helps!